# Powershell filter computers with no LAPS password set

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have recently deployed LAPS (Local admin password service) on our domain, and would now like to create a script I can run to find machines that have not yet communicated with AD to install the group policy extension and update their local admin password.

I can see that if I run:

```
Get-AdComputer -Identity Computer_Name -Properties *
```

I am presented with a computer that has updated its password, and shows the two properties:

```
ms-Mcs-AdmPwd
ms-Mcs-AdmPwdExpirationTime
```

My powershell is not great, so I may have the syntax wrong, but when trying to run:

```
Get-AdComputer -Filter {ms-Mcs-AdmPwd -ne ''}
```

I get an error that says:

```
The search filter cannot be recognised
```

Can anyone advise how I can filter on these two properties? Do I have to pipe into a Where-Object or perhaps even use LDAP filters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I think my issue was to do with me looking for attributes that had not yet been set.

I suspect there may be an ever so slightly more elegant way to filter, but the below works just fine for me:

```
 Get-ADComputer -Filter {ms-Mcs-AdmPwd -notlike "*"}
```

Answer (score 1):

The most appropriate way to do this is with an LDAP filter rather than a PowerShell filter. LDAP filters can test for existence, rather than comparing to a value that could be there (even if it's only remotely possible).

To get a list of computers WITH a password:

```
Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter "(ms-mcs-AdmPwd=*)"
```

And to find computers without one:

```
Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter "(!(ms-mcs-AdmPwd=*))"
```

You can combine that with other parameters to Get-ADComputer if you want to search a specific OU etc.

Answer (score 0):

If I run the command

`Get-ADComputer -Filter {ms-Mcs-AdmPwd -notlike '<not set>'}`

on my 2016 DC I get a list with all the computers with a password set.